# Add name to laravel route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I've got a route defined as:

```
Route::get('/novanoticia', 'HomeController@getNovaNoticia');
```

When I run `php artisan route:list` it shows nothing on the name column. How to add a name to the route in such a way that I can later call it just by its name like: `href="{{ route('route_name', $routeparam) }}`?

Or will I have to redefine the route? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
Route::get('/novanoticia', 'HomeController@getNovaNoticia')->name('route_name');
```

**Option 2**

```
Route::get('/novanoticia', ['as' => 'route_name', 'uses' => 'HomeController@getNovaNoticia']);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#named-routes

Comment: how can i set my custom route name into the modules in vendor folder route as naming route?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following step to name a route:

```
Route::get('/novanoticia', 'HomeController@getNovaNoticia')->name('route_name');
```

Also, you can use route naming conventions to name your routes so that you can recall them easily as below:

```
Route::get('/novanoticia', 'HomeController@getNovaNoticia')->name('controller_name.route_name');
```